# how to find the SVG text location before append the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

here is my code,

```
<html>
   <body>
      <svg id="text" height="400" width="400">
         <text transform="rotate(127,128,64)" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" font-weight="regular" font-style="Normal" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="12px" fill="#191919" y="68.25" x="128" id="caption">Revenue </text>
      </div>
  </body>
</html)
```

the text(Revenue) start 'x' location is 128. How to **find the 'x' location** of last char(e) of the text(Revenue) before append the text using jquery.
 Need a genuine calculation. Because the rotation of the degree is changeable.

After append possible to get using as follows,

```
var pos = document.getElementById("text").getStartPositionOfChar(6);
var matrix = document.getElementById("text").transform.animVal.getItem(0).matrix;
var position = pos.matrixTransform(matrix);
alert(position.x + ", " + position.y);
```

But, I need the same out put before append the text.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: i need to check whether it is overlap other div's(svg or out of the area). if it's overlap need to perform trim operation(Rev...)

Comment: No, I mean why do you need to do it in the opposite order to the order that works i.e. append the text and then find the location and then trim it.